# Append Key into JSON_OBJ_COLUMN - Oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

In Oracle **12c** I created one table with json objects.

Imagine the next sample:

| id | date | json_obj |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-MAY-2021 | { key_1: val1, key_2: val2} |

Now I want to **update key_2** value, and **append key_3: val3** into the same json object related with **id 1**.

That could be edited? or I must to overwrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that your DB version is **12R2+**, then you can use `PARSE()` and `PUT()` for object type `JSON_OBJECT_T` consecutively, and then apply a standard `UPDATE` statement such as

```
DECLARE
  jobj JSON_OBJECT_T;
  jdoc tab.json_obj%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT json_obj
    INTO jdoc
    FROM tab
   WHERE id = 1;

  jobj := JSON_OBJECT_T.PARSE( jdoc );
  jobj.PUT( 'key_2', 'val_22' );
  jobj.PUT( 'key_3', 'val_3' );  
  jdoc := jobj.TO_CLOB();

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( jdoc );
  
  UPDATE tab
     SET json_obj = jdoc
   WHERE id = 1;
END;
/
```